# Using proof by contradiction with the result instead of it's not?

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I think I understand proof by contradiction:
$$ If\ \{\Gamma,\lnot\phi\vdash\psi\}\ and\ \{\Gamma,\lnot\phi\vdash\lnot\psi\},\ then\ \{\Gamma\vdash\phi\}. $$
and likewise:
$$ If\ \{\Gamma,\phi\vdash\psi\}\ and\ \{\Gamma,\phi\vdash\lnot\psi\},\ then\ \{\Gamma\vdash\lnot\phi\}. $$

This leads me to believe given a formula:
$$ \{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\vdash p\} $$
I can assume $(p)$ for $\phi$ and the set$\{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\}$ for $\Gamma$, and then prove that $(p\vdash p)$ and $(p\vdash\lnot p),\ and\ therefore\ (\lnot p)$.

I got to $ \{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\vdash p\} $ from $ \vdash\{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\rightarrow p\} $, by assuming $ \vdash\{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\rightarrow p\} $ can come from $ \{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\rightarrow p\} $.

I think I am making a wrong assumption. I am told to prove $ \{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\rightarrow p\} $. May someone explain why what I have done above is wrong?

Edit: I am starting to think it is a typo because if p is false, the formula is false.

Comment: I don't know how you got to {(p→¬p)⊢p}, from what you posted above it.  I'm not getting there myself.  Can you detail exactly how you got there?

{(p→¬p)⊢p} won't hold for any sound formal system.  Suppose p false.  Then (p$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p) is true, and thus we have the true yielding the false.  Also, ((p$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p)$\rightarrow$p) is not a tautology, since when p is false, ((p$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p)$\rightarrow$p) is false also.

Comment: That's my line of thinking too. I put the first two formulas up for reference. I got to $\{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\vdash p\}$ from $\vdash\{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\rightarrow p\}$. I do see my mistake now though, because the original problem says to prove $\{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\rightarrow p\}$ and not $\vdash\{(p\rightarrow\lnot p)\rightarrow p\}$.

Comment: I thought it was okay to add the $\vdash$ in front.

Comment: " the original problem says to prove {(p→¬p)→p} and not ⊢{(p→¬p)→p}." What is the difefrence ?

Comment: As per comment above, you **cannot** prove $(p→¬p)→p$.

Comment: What you can prove is $(p→¬p)→¬p$.